# What is the status of SASL on macOS in 2019?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, sasl, cyrus

I have a linux application I am trying to compile on macOS. It relies on Cyrus SASL library.

During compilation I get deprecation warnings related to SASL, but the app compiles and seems to work.

```
/Users/travis/build/apache/qpid-proton/c/src/sasl/cyrus_sasl.c:101:30: warning: 'sasl_errdetail' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    const char* err = conn ? sasl_errdetail(conn) : sasl_errstring(r, NULL, NULL);
```

Cyrus SASL on linux comes with utility program `saslpasswd2`. This does not seem to be present on macOS.

I want to ask what is the Apple-recommended way to provide SASL on macOS that would give me the libraries to compile against and `saslpasswd2` utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyrus SASL can be installed using MacPorts, https://www.macports.org/.

```
sudo port install cyrus-sasl2
```

When this is done, then `/opt/local/sbin/saslpasswd2` is added to the system. Because `/opt/local/{bin,sbin}` is the default path where MacPorts installs things.

Answer (score 1):

When installing using Homebrew, the location is `/usr/local/Cellar/cyrus-sasl/2.1.27/sbin/`